# PHP-Spreadsheet: First Row Bold

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Because PHP-Excel is deprecated, PHP-Spreadsheet is the new Option to make Excel in PHP. The Documentation is not the best and the're not many questions on Stackoverflow about PHP-Spreadsheet, so that's why I make this Question about how to make the first row bold in PHP-Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
//Create Spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

//Create Styles Array
$styleArrayFirstRow = [
            'font' => [
                'bold' => true,
            ]
        ];

//Retrieve Highest Column (e.g AE)
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

//set first row bold
$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $highestColumn . '1' )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);
```

Answer (score 9):

A more compact way:

```php
//Create Spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

//Retrieve Highest Column (e.g AE)
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $highestColumn . '1' )->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

The last parameter `true` will set the bold, as `false` will unset it from a predefined bold cell / range.